# Adding elements to arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to add an element that holds type string and integer to an arraylist at position 2. I have some thing like

```
ArrayList<Data> arrl = new ArrayList<Data>();

        arrl.add(new Data("mike",29));
        arrl.add(new Data("Jim",49));
        arrl.add(new Data("kate",37));
        arrl.add(new Data(2, "Alex",31));
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I get an error on the last line saying the constructor data is undefined. I need some guidance.

EDIT.

I made a slight change to the last line which is

```
    arrl.add(2, new Data("Alex",31));

       for(int i=0;i<arrl.size();++i)
            {
                  arrl.get(i).Print();
            }
```

This prints the arraylist on a single line as opposed to a new element on each line. How do i correct this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add(int,%20E)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your arguments were misplaced (the 2 is an argument for `add`, you were placing it in the constructor of the `Data` object):

```
arrl.add(2, new Data("Alex",31));
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have a constructor for this

> new Data("mike",29)

But no constructor for this

> new Data(2, "Alex",31)

Chances are, that "2" should be a parameter to `arr1.add()`, not to `new Data()`.

Comment: That was me. What you've shown is not the actual problem. OP wants to insert an element at a specific position in the array; this has nothing to do with the `Data` class or its constructor(s).

Comment: Again, you're mistaken, the OP specifically stated that the problem is with the constructor.

Comment: `I am trying to add an element that holds type string and integer to an arraylist at position 2.` You've fixed the error, but you haven't solved the problem.

Comment: He didn't say anything about the problem being to do wiht inserting at a position.  He just said that he's trying to do that.  The problem that he's asking us to solve is to eliminate the error.

Comment: So, you let me get this correct, You made no attempt to help solve the problem, but felt the need to put yourself in charge of handing out downvotes.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you are mistaken. Yes, the "2, " should get removed, and the error goes away. But the "Alex" `Data` instance is not at position 2 in the array as OP explained he was trying to do, it is now at position 4. You've only fixed half of the issue.

Comment: @Hustl3r28: The correct answer was already posted when I got here. I removed my downvote after the last edit

Comment: @Hustl3r28 I think Cory's intentions were good enough, the downvotes did help.

Comment: Yep, they were good downvotes.  The conversation was also educational :)